# Optimize sql query by cover index

Tags: mysql, indexing

Query:

```
SELECT a, b, c FROM table WHERE a = .. and b like 'example%' and c = '..'
```

Does this query use index (a,b,c) or (a,b)?

Comment: Depends on so many things. What are the datatypes? Is the index in that order a,b,c for instance. Run `EXPLAIN SELECT a, b, c FROM table WHERE a = .. and b like 'example%' and c = '..'` and see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

For a covering index to even begin to help this query, it needs to be

```
a,c,b
```

That's because the query wants a specific single value for a and c and a range of values (`LIKE 'string%'`) for b.

The compound BTREE index gets random-accessed to the specific a,c value and the starting b value. It scans (in a so-called tight scan) to the last eligible b value.

Note that

```
c,a,b
```

will also work.

Comment: I understand that (a,c,b) would be better in this case, but this task form test, and I  should choose between (a), (a,b) and (a,b,c)